# Passing list as normal arguments to function in python

Tags: python

Say I have some code like this:

```
d = {'range': range}
args = [10]
d['range'](args)
```

args will be of variable content and length. I can handle any exceptions this would throw...
I can't change the function I'm calling (range is builtin), and it would be preferable to not wrap it. How can I make this code function properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The functionality that you are looking for is called [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
>>> d = {'range': range}
>>> args = [10]
>>> d['range'](*args)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>>
```

Comment: [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters) for more info